# Detecting touch event on empty UITextField

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios

When touching a UITextField that has no text in it, it does not get first responder. Is there any way to fix this?

```
    textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(margin, 0, frame.size.width - 2 * margin, frame.size.height)];
    textField.font = font;
    textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    textField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
    textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    textField.placeholder = caption;
    textField.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self addSubview:textField];
```

Comment: there should be no problem..... but you can check  userInteraction for textField.

Comment: i think u disabled its editable property in IB. check it.

Comment: I do this in code, and I am not disabling anything - I can get the first responder by touching exactly in the beginning - but not the entire frame of the textfield. So if I have text in 10% of the textfield, only that part of the textfield responds to touches.

Comment: can you post the code that creates and adds the textfield to it's superview?

Comment: Updated the question with a code sample

Comment: We need to know what's `frame.size.width - 2 * margin`

Comment: frame is the frame of the input field, margin is the top/right/bottom/left margin around the textfield in its superview

Comment: last line in your code is not making any sense. if you are extended your class by UIViewController then use - [self.view addSubview:textField];

Comment: also check is there any other thing is added or not.

Comment: I am extending my class by UIView, not UIViewController. Everything is added and layed out, its just this bug :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of view are you subclassing here?  If it's a UITableViewCell, you should be doing `[self.contentView addSubview:textField]`.

If that's not the issue, check to see if there's a transparent sibling subview overlapping part of your UITextField.  An easy way to do this is to temporarily set something like `siblingView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];` for each of your UITextField's siblings in the view hierarchy.

Comment: Just a plain UIView, and there is nothing overlapping it. I did exactly what you suggested and the textfield is displayed correctly without any overlapping views. Clicking the red area did not make the textfield get the first responder :/

Comment: Hmm... Try implementing this method to see which subviews is getting the event for each touch: `- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { UIView *recipient = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event]; NSLog(@"Recipient: %@", recipient); return recipient; }`